# AngularJS 1.x update nested property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, nested

I have problem with modification of nested property. How to watch these nested properties in task.history array? Or how to modify the $scope.$watch?

Here's plunker. Click *keyboard_arrow_up* icon.
http://plnkr.co/edit/ZCIU5gNwWfWdIOnz0ykb

```
<body ng-controller="EditController as ec">
    <!-- task history -->


    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>From</th>
                <th>To</th>
                <th>Time</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in ec.task.history">
                <td>{{ item.startTime | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</td>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <i class="material-icons" ng-click="ec.addHour(item.startTime)">keyboard_arrow_up</i>
                            <p style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px">{{ item.startTime | date:'HH'}}</p>
                            <i class="material-icons" ng-click="ec.substractHour()">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <p style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px">:</p>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_up</i>
                            <p style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px">{{ item.startTime | date:'mm'}}</p>
                            <i class="material-icons">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </td>

                <td>{{ item.stopTime | date:'HH:mm:ss '}}</td>
                <td>{{ item.dt | formatDuration }}</td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

EditController functions...

```
function addHour(timestamp) {
    console.log(timestamp);
    var tmp = new Date(timestamp);
    tmp.setHours(tmp.getHours() + 1);
    timestamp = tmp.toISOString();
}
$scope.$watch(angular.bind(self.task.history, function() {
    return self.task.history;
}), function(oldVal, newVal) {
    console.log(oldVal);
    console.log(newVal);
}, true);
```

Comment: what is the `task.history`?

Comment: Arrayy of objects like: { "startTime" :"2016-12-22T13:18:36.062Z","stopTime":"2016-12-22T13:19:42.100Z","_id":"585bd2ee9f2fee2f28e2551f","dt":66.038},

Comment: where did you declare that?

Comment: click http://plnkr.co/edit/ZCIU5gNwWfWdIOnz0ykb

Comment: Its just showing Loading.....

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it with `$scope.$watchCollection`??

see: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2566-scope-watch-vs-watchcollection-in-angularjs.htm for some background info.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$scope.$watch(angular.bind(self, function() {
    return self.task.history;
}), function(newVal) {
    console.log(newVal);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$watch or $watchCollection doesn't work. I've changed `addHour` function and pass `item` object and `property` parameter (as string). Now I don't need to use $watch or $watchCollection.

```
   function addHour(timestamp, property) {
          console.log(timestamp[property]);
          var tmp = new Date(timestamp[property]);
          tmp.setHours(tmp.getHours() + 1);
          timestamp[property] = tmp.toISOString();
          console.log(timestamp)          
      }
```

I use

```
ng-click="ec.addHour(item, 'startTime')"
```

instead

```
ng-click="ec.addHour(item.startTime)"
```